# Mocking axios and API get requests

Tags: typescript, jestjs, react-hooks, react-testing-library

I am writing an integration test for a form that receives a lot of values, one of which receives its data from another endpoint that is not its own.

```
/* eslint-disable camelcase */
import React from 'react';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';
import {
  cleanup, screen, act, waitFor, fireEvent, renderWithRecoilSnapshot,
} from 'testWrapper';
import * as institution from 'services/adminModules/institution';
import {
  generateMockInstitution, mockAxiosResponse,
} from 'helpers/testMocks';
import selectEvent from 'react-select-event';
import { institutionTypeAtom } from 'recoil/institution/institutionType';
import axios from 'axios';
import MockAdapter from 'axios-mock-adapter';
import InstitutionForm from '../../views/app/admin/InstitutionsPage/InstitutionForm';

let createInstitution: jest.SpyInstance;

const file = new File(['file contents'], 'teste.png', { type: 'image/png' });

const mockInstitution = generateMockInstitution(file);

const mockData: any = [
  { institution_type: 'Pública', institution_type_id: mockInstitution.institution_type_id },
];

const mockSubmit = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(mockInstitution);
const mockClose = jest.fn();
const mock = new MockAdapter(axios);

const renderComponent = () => renderWithRecoilSnapshot(
  <InstitutionForm
    handleClose={mockClose}
    handleSubmit={mockSubmit}
  />,
  ({ set }) => {
    set(institutionTypeAtom, mockData);
  },
);

describe('InstitutionFormPage', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    cleanup();
  });
  beforeEach(() => {
    createInstitution = jest.spyOn(institution, 'createInstitution').mockImplementation(async () => mockAxiosResponse());
    jest.spyOn(institution, 'getInstitution').mockImplementation(async () => mockAxiosResponse());
  });

  it('Should submit Institution Form', async () => {
    const { container } = renderComponent();
    const data = mock.onGet('/institution-types').reply(200, mockData);

    await waitFor(() => expect(screen.queryByText('loading')).not.toBeInTheDocument());


    const institution_type_id = screen.getByLabelText('institution_type_id');

    
    expect(institution_type_id).toBeInTheDocument();

    await act(async () => {
      await selectEvent.select(institution_type_id, mockData.map((d: any) => d.institution_type));
    });

    const institution_logo = screen.getByLabelText('institution_logo_file');

    const button = screen.getByRole('button', { name: /SALVAR/i });
    expect(button).toBeInTheDocument();

    await act(async () => {
      await userEvent.click(button);
    });

    await waitFor(() => expect(
      mockSubmit,
    ).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockInstitution, expect.anything()));
  });
});
```

And I am getting my mocked values from another file:

```
export const generateMockInstitution = (file: File): InstitutionFormType => ({
  institution_type_id: faker.datatype.uuid(),
  deleted: false,
});
```

The test, as it is, is working and passes as expected, without the need for the API to be up, as it should be. But for some reason, it still tells me that it is trying to fetch data from the server API and logs me the errors as such:

```
console.error src/services/adminModules/institution.ts:22
      Error on institution get: TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
    console.error node_modules/filter-console/index.js:46
      Error: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
```

I have tried to mock the axios response with axios-mock-adapter, but to no avail, as the error won't go away. The code I have tried is left on the test, and I have also tried to mock axios with jest diretcly, but am getting errors with headers and interceptors being undefined or unreachable.

How would I properly mock the API request for this test? Or at least make the warning go away?

Comment: You might want to mock the request _before_ you render your component.

Comment: Got it! Thank you!